# nginx match url unless it contains substring

Tags: regex, nginx

I am preparing an nginx HTML cache that uses a `map` of white listed URLs to determine which pages are cache-safe.

There are certain pages that are permissible to be cached, unless the word `edit` is in the string.

For example: `/users/123` would be safe to cache; however, `/users/123/edit` would be un-safe to cache

The map is as follows:

```
map $request_uri $skip_cache_whitelist {
    default 1;
    ~^/index.php 0;
    / 0;
    ~^/browse 0;
    ~^/contact 0;
    etc.
```

What I have tried is as follows:

```
~^/users(?!edit) 0;
~(^/users)(?!edit) 0;
~(?!edit)[^users] 0;
```

None of which work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposed solution is a regular expression with a *negative lookahead assertion*. Your current attempts fail to account for the `/123/` in-between the `users` and `edit` substrings.

I have tested the following:

```
map $request_uri $skip_cache_whitelist {
    default 1;
    ...
    ~^/users(?!.*edit) 0;
    ...
}
```

---

The regular expressions in a `map` are evaluated in order until a match is found. So an alternative to the *negative lookahead assertion* is two regular expressions with the more specific occurring first.

For example:

```
map $request_uri $skip_cache_whitelist {
    default 1;
    ...
    ~^/users/.*/edit 1;
    ~^/users         0;
    ...
}
```